# Tensorflow incompatible matrix size when using GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run code that previously worked on tensorflow 2.2.0 on version 2.4.0-rc0 for apple silicon (using python 3.8), but it is now generating the following error regarding the matrix dimensions:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: GetOutputShape: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,4], In[1]: [4,400]`

I am using nested gradient tapes to compute the gradient of my MLP model wrt the inputs (which form part of the loss), after which I compute the gradient of the loss wrt the trainable variables as below:

```
    def get_grad_and_loss(self, x, y):
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as gl_tape:
            gl_tape.watch(x)

            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as l_tape:
                l_tape.watch(x)
                y_pred = self.call(x)

            grad_mat = l_tape.gradient(y_pred, x)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y_pred - y[:, tf.newaxis])) + tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(0, -1 * (grad_mat[:, 0])))

        g = gl_tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)

        return g, loss
```

In words I am computing the MSE and trying to force the sign of the gradient to be positive (as a soft constraint). I have read through the documentation on [gradient tape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) and as I understand it, setting `persistent=True` should allow me to recompute gradients freely. As a side note my code works fine if I omit the nested gradient tape and simply use the MSE metric, so I don't think the issue lies anywhere else in the code. Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have confusion over which gradient tape watches which variables. I suggest to make sure that the tapes watch over different vars. Presently they both watch `x`.
Most likely you need to enter `gl_tape.watch(self.trainable_weights)`. There are examples out there with 2 gradient tapes working together. Check them out.

Comment: Yes I have taken a look and as in the documentation I linked above, they still watch the same 'x' variable and I still get the same error with your suggestion. I think the issue may be to do with MLCMatulGrad in the math_grad.py module (which I believe was adjusted by Apple in their tf fork), so there may still be some issues with it. Bear in mind that the above code works fine on my old machine with TF 2.2.0!

Comment: Not clear why you need both tapes to watch same variable. If indeed you need to - just make sure that you call gradient using dame variable that the tape watches after - otherwise you get inconsistent shapes. There may be a rare chance that shapes match and there is no error but this does not seem correct. If it works with TF2.2 -try to reproduce it in Colab with both 2.2 and 2.4. Send link to Colab here - I will check out.

Comment: I need both tapes as I need to compute higher order derivatives, namely the derivative wrt the trainable variables of the derivative wrt to the inputs of the model output (where the derivative of the model output wrt model input is defined by grad_mat in the code above). I have run a test case using colab and I believe this confirms that the issue lies with apple's fork (I raised the issue on github), here is the colab version in case you are interested https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SKDy-gVwRiymw_eF4fnaMs1E50has-of?usp=sharing

Comment: your example runs with both `gl_tape.watch(self.trainable_weights)` (which is more correct in my view) and `gl_tape.watch(x)`. However the model does not converge in either case because of the parameters relationship. See which tape option makes it converge with some other params.
Despite what I wrote above , your error message seems to be caused by some other issue in the apple fork. Hope the guys at GH will figure this out.

Comment: Yes I randomly generated some data just to check that the code works, but I am working with another dataset where the gradient constraints make sense and the model converges, thanks for taking a look at it though :)

Comment: Could you link to the github issue? I would like to see comments and if there is any resolution?

Comment: I don't think it's been addressed yet but here you go: https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/167#issuecomment-778371936